# How to show file preview using angular 4/5/6?

Tags: angular, angular5, thumbnails

I  want to display preview (Thumbnail) of file using angular 4/5/6.
file types will be  as below.

1. Excel
2. csv
3. PDF
4. Txt
5. jpeg

Is there any way  to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Where exactly are these files present?

Comment: @SiddAjmera   files are present in azure .

Answer (score 0):

For example we receive by the back-end an array buffer, to be sure we could check the http response by the browser, the pictures show three http preview examples: jpg, pdf and docx:

[image]

1) Case: direct access to the resource (example: //myserver/mydoc.extension) and public documents

We can use Google Document Viewer, with the tag  to display a remote hosted file

Example

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

2) Case: no direct access to the resource (example: local folder)

We can use for PDF file rendering, a library it is supported by Angular 5/6/7 +

ng2-pdf-viewer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

For docx file this:

mammoth: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth

3) Case: simple download

A solution could be, allow just the download without preview, saving performance of the browser, and giving the oppurtinity to the user to open the file with the favorite software

Angular Service (receiving an array buffer by the back-end)

```
downloadFile(file): Observable<any>{
    const url = '/download';
    const params = new HttpParams().set('filename', ''+ file);
    return this.http.post(url, params, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
}
```

Angular Component

```
download(doc) {
        this.service.downloadFile(doc.path).subscribe(response => {
            if(response) {
                let blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'blob' });
                if(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, doc.filename);                 
                }
            }   
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Iframe for that,
Please refer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_iframes.htm for more